# Realloc and uninitialized variables (valgrind)

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, heap-memory, valgrind

For the life of me, I can't figure out why Valgrind reports the following warnings:

```
==4988== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==4988==    at 0x4E62C3F: set_library (mainroutines.c:67)
==4988==    by 0x400E81: main (in /media/src/bin/driver)
==4988==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==4988==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4988==    by 0x4E6301F: create_input_data (supportroutines.c:43)
==4988==    by 0x400DAA: main (in /media/src/bin/driver)
==4988== 
==4988== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==4988==    at 0x4E62C61: set_library (mainroutines.c:68)
==4988==    by 0x400E81: main (in /media/src/bin/driver)
==4988==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==4988==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4988==    by 0x4E6301F: create_input_data (supportroutines.c:43)
==4988==    by 0x400DAA: main (in /media/src/bin/driver)
==4988==
```

Meanwhile, the `set_library` function appears like so:

```
void set_library (Foo* in_data, const int nrows, char* in_string) {
    const int str_length = strlen(in_string);
    char** new_string_array = NULL;

    if (in_data->stored_string==NULL) {
      in_data->stored_string = malloc(sizeof(char*)*1);
    } else {
      new_string_array = realloc(in_data->stored_string, sizeof(char*)*(nrows+1));
      in_data->stored_string = new_string_array;
    };  

    in_data->stored_string[nrows] = malloc(sizeof(char)*str_length);    // first uninitialized warning
    strcpy(in_data->stored_string[nrows], in_string);                   // second uninitialized warning
};
```

The declaration for `in_data->stored_string` is `char**`. I've also checked to make sure `stored_string = NULL` is done before the `set_library` function is called. When `realloc` is not called, I don't seem to get the error. Anyone have ideas what is causing the problem?

**EDIT---------------------**

D'oh! Opening up the debugger solved this. Actually, the snippet in question had a few problems. I placed the function to initialize values inside the wrong `if` bracket. Anyways, valid points were raised in the comments, so....

```
void set_library (Foo* in_data, const int nrows, char* in_string) {
    const int str_length = strlen(in_string)+1;
    char** temp_string_array = NULL;

    temp_string_array = realloc(in_data->stored_string, sizeof(*in_data->stored_string)*(nrows+1));
    in_data->stored_string = temp_string_array;
    in_data->stored_string[nrows] = malloc(sizeof(char)*str_length);    
    strcpy(in_data->stored_string[nrows], in_string);  
}
```

Comment: You really don't need to check for `NULL`, since `realloc(NULL, n)` is the same as `malloc(n)`.

Comment: Can `in_data->stored_string` be `NULL` with `n != 0`? In that case I think the `malloc()` call should multiply by `n+1` instead of `1`.

Comment: Run a debugger to make sure everything makes sense here, we don't have enough information to figure it out.  A couple notes: `strcpy()` is definitely a buffer overflow, because the buffer doesn't have space for a NUL terminator.  Since you know the length, you can use `memcpy()`.  And `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition.

Comment: All good suggestions. @Dietrich debugging session hit the nail on the head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D'oh! Opening up the debugger solved this. Actually, the snippet in question had a few problems. I placed the function to initialize values inside the wrong `if` bracket. Anyways, valid points were raised in the comments, so....

```
void set_library (Foo* in_data, const int nrows, char* in_string) {
    const int str_length = strlen(in_string)+1;
    char** temp_string_array = NULL;

    temp_string_array = realloc(in_data->stored_string, sizeof(*in_data->stored_string)*(nrows+1));
    in_data->stored_string = temp_string_array;
    in_data->stored_string[nrows] = malloc(sizeof(char)*str_length);    
    strcpy(in_data->stored_string[nrows], in_string);  
}
```